# Hashtable, свой ключ

Tags: c#

Создаю коллекцию типа Hastable, где в качестве ключа - случайно сгенерированная строка, а value - значение типа int.

```
public void AddElements()
{
    int collectionLength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int key = 0; key < collectionLength; key++)
        internalHashtable.Add(RandomClass.CreateRandomString(), key);
}

public void ShowElements()
{
    foreach (var s in internalHashtable)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t", s);
}
```

На экран выводит System.Collection.DictionaryEntry для каждого элемента. Если вызвать `internalHashtable.Count` то показывает количество элементов, равное collectionLength. Методы делал по аналогии с SortedList.

Comment: А вопрос, собственно, в чем заключается?

Comment: хотелось бы увидеть на консоли уникальные элементы, а не System.Collection.DictionaryEntry

Comment: не совсем понял на счет дубликатов, вы имеете в виду ключ? так он имеет длину 10 символов и включает в себя рандом из цифр и букв обоих регистров. Обязательно надо сделать это в HashTable.

Comment: Кажется понял в чем именно заключается проблема, тогда вот так: `foreach (DictionaryEntry s in internalHashtable)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}:\t{1}", s.Key, s.Value);`

Comment: лучше Dictionary<string,int> использовать - он даст типизированное значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш метод `public void ShowElements()` должен выглядеть, например, следующим образом:

```
public void ShowElements()
{
   foreach (DictionaryEntry s in internalHashtable)
      Console.WriteLine("{0}:\t{1}", s.Key, s.Value);
}
```